# AWS Fargate instance unable to make a request to another instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, aws-security-group

I have two ECS clusters, both running fargate 1.3 tasks (lets call them task A and task B). Both tasks have network type awsvpc and both have auto assigned public IPs. Furthermore, both clusters/tasks are in the same VPC. Task A is associated with security group A, task B is associated with security group B (as well as a load balancer that is also connected with the security group). I am trying to making an http request from task A to task B. I'm 100% sure I have the security groups set up properly, namely:

security group A:

- egress to anywhere

security group B:

- ingress to security group A (Port range All, Protocol All, Type "All Traffic")

When I try to make the request from A to B, I get a time out error. I know it is a security group error, because if I create an ingress rule with Source = everywhere, it works. Furthermore, if I go in and check the public IP address of fargate task A, and add that IP address to the ingress of security group B, it also works.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using public (Internet) IPs, the traffic is going outside of the VPC and back in, at which point the fact that the traffic originated from security group A is lost. You need to use private IPs to keep all network traffic within the VPC.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have used an auto assigned public IP for task A so that it could access the internet (both to pull from ECR as well as a few other HTTP requests that are coming out of task A that access something outside of AWS). Am I correct in thinking that only workaround here is to attach a NAT gateway to my private subnet?

Comment: I don't have a Fargate task I can look at at the moment, but doesn't each task also get a private IP? You just need to change Task A to reference Task B via Task B's private IP.

Comment: Thanks! Just to follow back here, I was able to get this working by adding service discovery to the fargate tasks (otherwise those private IPs will change when the task gets recreated), and call the service discovery endpoint from task A instead of the load balancer endpoint.